# Сократить код C++

Tags: c++, qt

Добрый вечер! Есть такой код

```
void ChangeDB::changePhotoLat(int id, double lat)
{
    query.prepare("UPDATE Points SET lat = :lat WHERE id = :id;");
    query.bindValue(":id", id);
    query.bindValue(":lat", lat);

    if (!query.exec()){
        qDebug() << "Error SQLite:" << query.lastError().text();
    }
}

void ChangeDB::changePhotoLon(int id, double lon)
{
    query.prepare("UPDATE Points SET lon = :lon WHERE id = :id;");
    query.bindValue(":id", id);
    query.bindValue(":lon", lon);

    if (!query.exec()){
        qDebug() << "Error SQLite:" << query.lastError().text();
    }
}
```

Такие функции мне нужно сделать для всех столбцов в бд. Как можно оптимально записать это дело?

Comment: И много таблиц / столбцов?

Comment: Может одновременно изменять оба (или больше) столбцов: `UPDATE Points SET lat = :lat, lon = :lon WHERE id = :id`.

Comment: Тут фишка в том, что это функции класса, который в свою очередь позволяет изменять поля по-одному
типо:

    class.changePhotoLat(15, 35.55555)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как можно заметить, в этих функциях у вас меняется только название колонки.
поэтому например можно названия всех столбцов сохранить в массиве

`QStringList columns[] = {"lat", "lon", ...}`

тогда вам нужна будет только одна функция которая принимает этот массив в качестве параметра в которой можно пройтись по этому циклу и обновить этот столбец в базе данных

`void ChangeDB::changePhotoL(int id, double c, const QStringList& columns);`

Comment: Или, будет лучше сделать `enum`, содержащий имена столбцов и функцию, которая по значению из `enum'a` возвращает стрковое название. Тогда функциия `change*()` будет принимать значение из `enum'a`, а потом преобразовывать его в строку в бинде. Так будет проще контролировать сис-му